# Coded human body parts

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, pattern

The table gives information about some of the human body parts.

The names of the body parts are all coded and the count of those body parts present in a normal human are given.

| Coded body part | Count |
| --- | --- |
| AH | 1 |
| MN | 2 |
| AIT | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| BIMU | 2 |
| AHIIP | 10 |
| **???** | 206 |

**What codeword (of length 3) will complete the table?**

Comment: Not enough data on how to decode existing parts. There's a lot of paired organs in a normal human, and quite a bunch of singular ones. Since all codes seem to be mandatorily shorter than the words (including expected "BONE" for the answer, derived from the number), and AHIIP therefore means "FINGER" and not "TOE", and the answer being 3 letters long, I can only assume the "code" is shorter by 1 than the body part name. Yet, there's no body part for "A" and 1, since they all have names that are longer than 2 letters.

Comment: @Vesper Probably there is not enough data to decode as you said. But if I add even a tiny detail, many of them will solve it within minutes. I am interested to see if someone will decode it with the existing information. You can call it an experiment.

Comment: Oh, this one is really easy. I think we know by now, what AHIIP means rot13(naq gung gur pbqrf ner bar fubegre guna gur jbeq. Nyfb abgr gung nyy pbqrf ner beqrerq nycunorgvpnyyl. Gur pncvgny bs .sv vf Uryfvaxv naq gurer'f na U evtug gurer! Gur pncvgny bs .va vf Arj Qryuv. Ab ceboyrz, yrg'f erjevgr gr ehyr: Gnxr gur ynfg yrggre: gjb Vf sebz Uryfvaxv naq Qryuv, na N sebz Nohwn ...) Yeah, it doesn't work ...

Comment: @MOehm I tried to see if there was a connection to Purzvpny ryrzragf nyfb, but that didn't help either

Comment: Could we know as an extra hint,if AHI and AHII encode something (and the related count)?

Comment: @franckvivien The whole AHIIP encodes that body part.

Comment: @Prim3numbah: Hehe. The good thing is that it can't be UK postcode districts – only Stiv uses those .. `:)`

Comment: @MOehm You and Prim3numbah have the right kind of thinking to solve this puzzle!

Comment: @Prim3numbah You and M Oehm have the right kind of thinking to solve this puzzle!

Comment: Your style of puzzlecraft means you may be able to come up with something for this month's [Monthly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7484/60644) - this month it's about puzzles you can solve easily on a mobile with some kind of 'innovative' element to them. You should take a look...

Comment: @Stiv Oh! Will definitely look into it. Thanks for finding me worthy of it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since there are 206 bones (and not a lot else in that exact quantity) in the typical adult human body, it's no secret that we seek a 3-letter code for the word BONE. This would be:

> **ALN**

Why? Because the method used to encode body parts in this puzzle involves...

> ...finding **the name of a country** (in English) that contains the letters of the body part in question (not necessarily in order), removing those letters, and then alphabetising what remains!

For the examples given:

> AH (1) = BRAIN from B(ah)RAIN
>  MN (2) = EYE from YE(m)E(n)
>  AIT (1) = NOSE from ES(t)ON(ia)
>  A (1) = CHIN from CHIN(a)
>  BIMU (2) = LEG from (b)ELG(ium)
>  AHIIP (10) = TOE from ET(hi)O(pia)

So to get BONE we need:

> **ALN (206) = BONE from (l)EB(a)NO(n)**

Comment: Nicely done! Out of curiosity, can I ask how did you decode?

Comment: But then there's no one-to-one correspondence for encoding. The word encoded A could've been encoded EEEILNSTT instead, for example.

Comment: @msh210 I'm not disputing that. I thought about it too which is why I specified the length of the required codeword in the question. I appreciate your comment. Sometimes I am deliberately interested in knowing how much information should be revealed in the puzzle which was why I shared this question.

Comment: @msh210 Perhaps we should consider just the shortest candidates?

Comment: @chandanr777 The thing I'd noticed that hadn't been mentioned in comments was that rot13(gur yrggref jrer neenatrq nycunorgvpnyyl. Guvf tbg zr guvaxvat nobhg nantenzf engure guna qverpg fhofgvghgvba pvcuref (juvpu V unq cerivbhfyl orra svkngrq ba). V jnf nyfb hapbaivaprq gung SVATRE jnf gur vagragvba sbe 10, fvapr jr bayl unir 8 (gjb guhzof!). Gura V gubhtug 'jung vs jr'er erzbivat ZBER GUNA BAR yrggre?' naq abgvprq gung NUVVC cyhf GBR tnir RGUVBCVN. Gur erfg sbyybjrq.)

Comment: @msh210 Having said that, the fifth one could equally be encoded AAIR, which is the same length... But all things considered, I think it's still valid to think of this puzzle as a case of 'these body parts have been obfuscated in some way - can you work out what I did, and do similarly for this example...?' rather than necessarily expecting it to be a formal 1-1 reversible cipher system. The body parts just *can* and *have* been 'encoded' in this pattern-like way that we need to spot. This won't be the next big player in cyber-security hashing! :)

Comment: @Stiv Nice to know! I somehow predicted AHIIP would be the key code in solving it.

Comment: I too object to the "cipher" tag. This isn't encryption. Anagrams, abbreviations, acrostics, and lipograms are better categorized as "wordplay".